# PostgreSQL : Cannot convert JSON to row result

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, unnest

I have the JSOn data in a table of PostgreSQL database.

```
{
    "city": "NY",
    "country": "US",
    "sales": [145, 222, 122, 124, 172],
    "dates": ["13.05.2020", "2.05.2020", "21.05.2020", "30.04.2020", "29.04.2020"]
}
```

I want to convert these values to row result as I do in JSON data, but as this is an array I have not managed to evaluate result even if looking at **[JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)**.

I am trying something like that at the first step:

```
select * from json_array_elements(select info ->> 'sales' from my_table)
```

And waiting for such a result:

```
sales
------
145
222
122
124
172
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a lateral join:

```
select s.*
from my_table mt
  cross join lateral json_array_elements_text(info -> 'sales') as s
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It seems to work, but what is the behind of this approach? Sorry, I am new in PostgreSQL, and look at an easier way because it is so common situation and there may be smarter solutions for this need. Any idea?

Comment: Also there is no info such a kind of approach, could you pls suggest some resource to get information regarding to that? Does postgresql manual contains such kind of info?

Comment: And also, should we use cross join always for this kind of data retrieval (from arrays)? Or sometimes left/right/inner join for this kind of scenarios?

Comment: @Jason: see the chapter about set returning functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS

Comment: I look at that manual that is really lack of examples with JSON. Is there another resource with enough example? And what if I want to get the other fields with this query in your answer?

Comment: And also where is **lateral** in your answer?

Comment: @Jason: the lateral keyword is optional for functions returning a result set as explained in the link in my last comment